# Update all values in a column of different fields form (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

> **I have in my students table :**

```
             id | fname | gname | course | year |
           ----------------------------------------
               1| user 1| user 1|  IT    |  5   |
           ----------------------------------------
               2| user 2| user 2|  CompE |  3   |
           ----------------------------------------
               3| user 3| user 3| Nursing|  2   |
```

> **In my controller I am using **HASH*** to display the Student info*

```
def index
  @students = Student.all
  @studentlist = HASH.new
   @students.each do |s|
     @studentlist[s.id] = s
   end
end
```

> **In my Index View I have this**

```
<%=form_tag "/students/update_year" do%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <TH>Family Name</TH>
        <TH>Year</TH>
    </tr>
    <%@studentlist.each_key do |key|%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=@studentlist[key].id%></td>
            <td><%=@studentlist[key].fname%></td>
            <td><%=collection_select(:student,:year,Student.select('distinct year') , :year , :year ,:selected=>@studentlist[key].year %></td>
        </tr>       
    <%end%>
</table>
<%=submit_tag("Update")%>
```

- I want to change the year of the students and click the Update but my Problem is when I Update it all of the value in **year** column will be change and will have the same value.

> This my controller **update_year** action :

```
def update_year
   @students = Student.all
   @studentlist = HASH.new
   @students.each do |s|
      @studentlist[s.id] = s
       @studentlist.each_key do |key|
       @student = Student.find(@studentlist[key].id)
       @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
     end
  end
 end
```

*It will not update or the value will not be updated to I have set on my `collection_select`*

Please help me ! 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you learn something from this answer.

```
def index
  @students = Student.all
  @years = Student.uniq.pluck(:year)
end

index.html.erb

<% @students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= student.id %></td>
    <td><%= student.fname %></td>
    <td>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'student[][id]', student.id %>
      <%= select :student, :year, @years, { selected: student.year }, { name: 'student[][year]' } %>
    </td>
  </tr>       
<% end %>
```

The code above creates your table without using a hash. It also creates fields that will generate a hash when you submit the form.  The hash will look like

```
params[:student] = [{ id: 1, year: 1 }, { id: 2, year: 2}]
```

`id` is the `student_id`, `year` is the selected year in the dropdown.  Given this, you can use the following code for `update_year`

```
def update_year
  params[:students].each do |student|
    student = Student.find(student[:id])
    student.update_attributes(year: student[:year])
  end
end
```

DISCLAIMER: The code above isn't tested and was written trying to help you understand how you can solve your issue.

Comment: I've tried the code and it gives me `undefined method each for nil Class`  pointing the error to the controller **update_year** action

Comment: I got it already .. In my update_year action I just add `@` in `student = Student.find(student[:id]` and also in `student.update_attributes(year: student[:year])`.. Sot it looks like this in my code... `@student = Student.find(student[:id])
    @student.update_attributes(year: student[:year])`..

Comment: you don't need to do that.  You're probably using `@student` in the `update_year` view template which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you using hash to display tables?
2. In your update_year action is not wise to get all students from db, because it is time and db consuming and you don't need it..

Comment: how can i do it to update all my year column in just one form